# Jekyll serve generate wrong path in localhost

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I believe this is caued by gem "github-pages". When I run `bundle exec jekyll serve`, all the links is generated with a prefix of `/pages/<user_name>` or `/pages/<user_name>/<repo_name>` depends on `repository` in _config.yml.

For example, `/js/jquery.js` becomes `/pages/<user_name>/js/jquery.js`. This make all the JavaScript, CSS, and page broken.

However, it generates fine if it is built by GitHub. Also, if I remove `repository` in _config.yml cause the following error.

> GitHub Metadata: Error processing value 'baseurl':
>
> Liquid Exception: No repo name found. Specify using PAGES_REPO_NWO environment variables, 'repository' in your configuration, or set up an 'origin' git remote pointing to your github.com repository. in /_layouts/layout.html
>
> ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
>
> ---
>
> No repo name found. Specify using PAGES_REPO_NWO environment variables, 'repository' in your configuration, or set up an 'origin' git remote pointing to your github.com repository.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `JEKYLL_ENV` to `development` solved the problem.

On Windows, you can run the following:

```
set JEKYLL_ENV=development
```